# Does `select` tries to send before default?

Tags: go

In the code below is there a guarantee that Go will try to send on errCh before to exit the select (default), is it random/undefined?  I find the specification very confusing because it says that if there is a "default case" that case is chosen but it doesn't seem to be true. The code below prints "hello"

> >
>    If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen.

```
func main() {
    errCh := make(chan error, 1)
    select {
    case errCh <- fmt.Errorf("hello"):
    default:
    }
    err := <-errCh
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need to know is in the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one of the communications can proceed.

If multiple non-`default` cases in a select are able to proceed, one of them is chosen at random. But the `default` is only chosen if none of the other cases can proceed without blocking.

Comment: I actually read the spec and updated my question as well(before to see your answer). To me is still confusing because it's not specified `multiple non-default cases`, it only says `If one or more of the communications can proceed` so `default` could be interpreted  as a possible `communication`. That being said I take your answer as an assurance.

Comment: @Mihai What "channel communication" happens in your default case?

Comment: @Volker It doesn't mention "channel communication". It says "communications". default is an "option" that "communicates" that select can can always proceed if it chooses to. I believe the language/spec could be a bit more clear.

Comment: @Mihai The spec is open source you can improve it.

Comment: The communication it's referring to is channel communications. `default` does no channel communication. The spec seems very clear in its explanation.

Comment: `default` does no communication of *any* kind.